# Reading data with Zend_Soap_Client

Tags: php, soap, zend-soap

I am new to `Zend_Soap_Client`. I have the following code as an example, and I try to understand what is behind it. Do I understand correctly that it connects to remote server and reads specified data? Finally, as far as I understand, it is supposed to save these data in `test.txt`.

I tried to run this code (I have the necessary certificate). The problem is that no data is saved to `test.txt`. So, could someone please explain me this technology or give me a link to a good tutorial on similar topic? In particular, I'm very interested in how to save necessary data to local XML file or array.

P.S. I apologize if I used some incorrect definitions, because as I mentioned at the beginning I'm new to `Zend_Soap_Client` and the related technology.

```
$wsdl = 'tttest.wsdl';

$options = array(
    'local_cert' => 'certificate.pem',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
);

$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl, $options);

$p = array(
    'endUserId' => 'demo',
    'sendTime' => array('value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
    'eaupId' => array('chainDate' => array('value' => $chaindate), 'sequenceNumber' => 1)
);
$webServices = $client->retrieveEAUPCDRs($p);

$line = $client->getLastResponse();
$line = substr($line, 110);
$line = substr($line, 0, -22);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($line);

$result = $xml->xpath('//@ns3:title | //ns2:beginPosition | //ns2:endPosition | //ns4:upperLimit | //ns4:lowerLimit | //ns8:conditionalRouteType');

$filename = 'test.txt';
if ($fh = fopen($filename, "r")) {
    while (!feof($fh)) {
        $line = fgets($fh);
        if (strlen($line) != 0) {
            $chars = explode(";", $line, 5);
            $np[$chars[0]] = "$chars[3],$chars[2]";
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does NOT do what you think it is doing.

The first two-thirds (up to and including the call to `xpath()`) do connect to a server and grab some information, which is ultimately placed in the `$result` variable. However, the last 11 lines do not utilize any of the data from the previous code (`$line` is being re-used in the last bit).

Furthermore, `fopen()` is being called with the "r" option, which means read-only.

I would recommend spending some time on http://php.net researching the various PHP functions and language constructs that are being used in this code and then visiting the Zend Framework Manual for additional info on `Zend_Soap_Client`: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/manual.html